# Native keyboard bar AIR iOS

Tags: ios, air, keyboard, air-native-extension

Is there any way to display in AIR iOS app bar with "previous | next" and "done" keys?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using StageText, you can dynamically change the label of the soft keyboard's DONE button label by setting a StageText instance's *returnKeyLabel* property to one of the static properties in the ReturnKeyLabel class: DONE, GO, NEXT, or SEARCH (there's a fifth property named DEFAULT which is the same as DONE on iOS). There's no ReturnKeyLabel.PREVIOUS property, although you could use the StageText method *assignFocus()* to set the focus to a different StageText instance on the stage when a certain event occurs.

Here's a simple example in which the soft keyboard's DONE button is changed to NEXT. You could put the following code in frame 1 of a .fla:

```
import flash.text.StageText;
import flash.text.ReturnKeyLabel;

var st:StageText = new StageText();
st.stage = this.stage;
st.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 333, 33);
st.editable = true;
st.returnKeyLabel = ReturnKeyLabel.NEXT;
st.assignFocus(); // This causes the soft keyboard to appear
```

Note that the StageText class doesn't have a property for setting a border. However, if you look on GitHub you'll find a NativeText class that simplifies things by wrapping the StageText class and adding properties such as borderThickness and borderColor:

[StageTextExample on GitHub](https://github.com/nixxle/StageTextExample)